# try and catch blocks in return methods

Tags: java, exception

I'm fairly new to using try and catch statements and I'm having a bit of trouble with return statements. Upon compiling my code I got an `unreported IOException` in:
`fileFtp = client.listNames();` So I tried wrapping this statement in a try and then wrote a catch for the exception but then the fileName array was no longer visible, so I wrapped the entire method in a `try{}` and used a catch at the end and put the return statement which returned the fileName after the end of the `catch{}`, but this didn't work either since fileName was no longer visible as it was in the `try{}` So how can I meet the exception report requirements while still having fileName and fileFtp arrays initialized?

```
 private String[] checkDirectories(){

    String[] fileFtp;
    String[] fileName;

    try{        
        fileFtp = client.listNames();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("IOException in checkDirectories()");
        ex.printStackTrace();     
    }

    fileName = new String[fileFtp.length];
        for (int i=0; i<fileFtp.length; i++){
            fileName[i] =   fileFtp[i];
        }            
        return fileName;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not visible"?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't putting the statements you have after the catch block inside the try block?

Comment: as I said, i tried wrapping that code in the try block but it couldn't return fileName as the fileName was in the try{}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be catching the exception here, when you do that you don't give the calling code any indication that the operation failed. Let the exception be thrown so that the caller can realize that something went wrong and deal with it:

```
private String[] checkDirectories() throws IOException {

    String[] fileFtp = client.listNames();
    String[] fileName = new String[fileFtp.length];
    for (int i=0; i<fileFtp.length; i++) {
        fileName[i] =   fileFtp[i];
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

Throwing an exception lets the code get out of its current path of execution so that it's not operating on invalid data, and it signals to calling code that something went wrong. If you catch the exception and return null here than calling code has to check for null and decide whether or not to proceed.

Comment: and would I just put the try and catch over the code that calls the method which throws?

Comment: @joe: not necessarily. it depends on whether that code can do anything to handle the exception usefully. for a lot of exceptions the best thing is to let them go until a central handler can log them. it's a judgment call that depends on what your application needs.

Comment: Ok so I have another method which calls checkDirectories and stores it's returned array in another array:  String[] directories = checkDirectories();  This is now getting an unreported exception error when compiling, so do I need wrap this is try{} catch{}?

Comment: Nvm - got it. Just made directories variable null and put try block over calling it

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you asked but you should probably try  this:

```
private String[] checkDirectories()
{

    String[] fileFtp = null;
    String[] fileName = null;
    try
    {
    fileFtp = client.listNames();
     fileName = new String[fileFtp.length];
        for (int i=0; i<fileFtp.length; i++)
        {
            fileName[i] =   fileFtp[i];
        }
    }
        catch(IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println("IOException in checkDirectories()");
    ex.printStackTrace();

}



        return fileName;
}
```